# Can I display a list of sorted items in Grafana?

Tags: graphite, grafana

I would like to display a list of the X largest of a quantity, for a given time period, in grafana.  Is that possible?

To make the problem more concrete, let's say I'm storing execution times for a sequence of jobs in graphite like this `jobs.[one two three four five...].duration`, and every time a job is finished I record the duration.

Now I would like to have a panel display the 3 most expensive jobs (from most to third most expensive), something like:

```
twelve:  55 sec.
three:   39 sec.
eight:   25 sec:
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to wrap you metric list in `limit(sortByMaxima(...), 3)` function